# Making sense of a combinatorial answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\frac {\sum^n_{k= 0}k\binom nk}{2^n}$ is the average size of a subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

We add up the sizes of all subsets and divide by the total number of subsets. Why is the $i$th term in the numerator is of the for $k\binom nk$? I mean what's the point of $k$ in front of $\binom nk$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}k$ subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with cardinality $k$, so they contribute a total of $k\binom{n}k$ to the sum of the cardinalities of all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. The $k$ is the size of a subset; the $\binom{n}k$ is the number of subsets of that size.

Answer (score 2):

The average size of the subsets of an $n$ element set, $S$, is given by $$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{A \subset S} card(A).$$

We can break this down as follows:

$$\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot \left( \text{Number of subsets with size } k \right)$$

The number of subsets of $S$ with size $k$ is given by ${n \choose k}$ and so $$\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot {n\choose k}$$ is the average size of subsets of $S$.

We can arrive at a closed form for the sum. In particular, note that $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k = (1+x)^n.$$ With a little calculus this gives: $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k x^{k-1} = n (1+x)^{n-1}.$$ Evaluating this at $x=1$ yields: $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k = n 2^{n-1}$$ and so the average size of subsets of $S$ is given by $$\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: It may be interesting to notice that we can avoid differentiation by simply coupling the first term of the sum with the last one and so on, that is more or less the same as considering a subset and its complement at once.

Comment: That's true. It did occur to me; basically it's the symmetric nature of Pascal's triangle. I just felt like doing a little calculus.